# Unity3d Facebook SDK login with browser

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game application using Unity3d tool. In that I shared some texts and photos in Facebook. So that I have used Facebook SDK(Prime31).

**Case 1: Facebook app already installed**

```
    If login the facebook from my app, the facebook application's login screen is opened.
```

**Case 2: Facebook not installed**

```
    If login the facebook from my app, the browser will open the facebook login screen.
```

**My question:** Is it possible to open the browser window for facebook login even the **Facebook app already installed**?

**Reason:** If I use the case 2, the facebook login is success. But If I use the case 1, the facebook login is failed and it shows the "Invalid access token error". This is happened only in the "HTC" mobile devices. So I want to use case 2 even facebook app installed in the device.

If possible Can you give me the steps to do that?

Comment: Is this to allow the user to switch accounts, or what is the purpose?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Because, If I use the case 2, the facebook login is success. But If I use the case 1, the facebook login is failed and it shows the "Invalid access token error". This is happened only in the "HTC" mobile devices. So I want to use case 2 even facebook app installed in the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Facebook's SDK chooses how authentication occurs. We couldn't choose that one.

Finally I got this answer from Prime31 plugin forum.

Answer (score 0):

You better ask them [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/92154-Prime31-Android-Plugins-Officially-Live!) instead of asking people on StackOverflow. Ask them on forum, PM  or Email them on their page.